# What is a $C^{n}$ surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

I know the definition of a regular surface (a set) and a continous/differentiable/regular parametrized surface (a map). But what is a $C^{n}$ surface?

Is a $C^{n}$ surface the image of a $C^{n}$ paramterized surface? I've a theorem where they introducea $C^{2}$ surface and use its Gaussian curvature. But Gaussian curvature is only defined for regular surfaces?

Can someone help me clarify this notation?

Comment: $C^n$ usually means "n times differentiable such that the n'th derivative is continuous". So a differentiable parametrizied surface would be probably $C^1$. also note, that $C^2 \subset C^1$

Comment: Very likely.
But isn't the Gaussian curvature only defined for regular surfaces?  In the theorem they introduce the $C^{2}$ surface where a point $p$ on it has a vanishing Gaussian curvature.

Comment: how is regular surface defined in your case? I thought that would be $C^1$ too, but probably i am wrong

Comment: I define a regular surface as a set $S$ where for all points $p\in S$ exists a neighborhood $V$ and a map $\sigma_{p}:U\rightarrow V\cap S, U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ open such that:

$\sigma_{p}$ is smooth. homeomorphism and for each $u\in U$ the jacobian matrix has linearly independent columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that for each point $x$ in our surface $S$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $S$ around $x$ and a homeomorphism $\phi : U \to \tilde{U}$ where $\tilde{U}$ is some open subset of $\Bbb R^2$. This is the "locally Euclidean" property of manifolds (and in particular, surfaces). We call such a neighborhood and homeomorphism a chart.

Now suppose we have two charts $(U, \phi)$ and $(V, \psi)$ such that $U\cap V \neq \emptyset$. We can consider the "transition function" $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$ which is a homeomorphism from $\phi(U\cap V)$ to $\psi(U\cap V)$. As it is a map between open subsets of $\Bbb R^2$, we know what it means for it to be $C^n$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, \infty$.

A $C^n$ surface is a surface on which we have chosen charts such that all of the transition functions between overlapping charts are $C^n$ maps. Thus, we do not include all possible charts, but instead choose a subset for which all the transition functions are $C^n$. An additional assumption is that the domains of the charts we choose must cover the entire surface.

You can [check out this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Definition) for more information.

Comment: Okay this makes sense. I know what a differentiable manifold is. So I assume you still can compute the Gaussian curvature of a $C^{2}$ surface even though it's not a regular surface (a $C^{\infty}$ surface)?

Comment: Yes. You only need second derivatives to define Gaussian curvature, so that's all you need assume makes sense on your surface. Of course, many times books and courses will assume all manifolds to be $C^\infty$ to make life simpler.